# Sorting ArrayList of model that is connected with a hashmap

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I have an arraylist of model and a hashmap. The model class contains variable such as id(int), name, address, etc. The hashmap, contains id(int) and distance (double). I have tried using Collection to sort a list of model before, but the problem here is, I have to sort the hashmap by it's distance value, and then adjust the arraylist according to how the hashmap sorted. The hashmap's id and the model class' id here act as a "foreign key". Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Here is the hashmap:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> listDistance = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
listDistance.put(1, 3.22);
listDistance.put(2, 2.57);
listDistance.put(3, 6.32);
listDistance.put(4, 8.82);
listDistance.put(5, 1.32);
```

Here is the arraylist:

```
ArrayList<Listing> listings = new ArrayList<Listing>();
listing.add(1, "asd", 123);
listing.add(2, "ghf", 3434);
listing.add(3, "ert", 876);
listing.add(4, "tyi", 1267);
listing.add(5, "ohg", 1345);
```

Here is the model class:

```
public class Listing {

int id, count;
String name;

public Listing(int id, String name, int count) {
    this.id = id;
    this.count = count;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

The result of what I want should sort the listings to become like this:

1. listing.add(5, "ohg", 1345);
2. listing.add(2, "ghf", 3434);
3. listing.add(1, "asd", 123);
4. listing.add(3, "ert", 876);
5. listing.add(4, "tyi", 1267);

I actually haven't tried anything to make this works except thinking the logical flow because I am quite out of idea as to how to do this.

Comment: show something you've worked on already.

Comment: Try TreeMap instead HashMap.., B/W Show us your code

Comment: Could you please post some code of your model and the way you are sorting now.

Comment: Do you truly need the `Map<Integer, Double>` sorted by value *(which cannot be done)*, or do you just need the `List<Model>` sorted by distance *(which can easily be done)*?

Comment: yes, as long as the list of model can be sorted by distance, then it is good. But i don't think i can merge the value of the distance into the list of model. Because the data is retrieved separately and have to put the distance value according to the id. Or can i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the list like this:

```
Collections.sort(listing, (a,b) -> Double.compare(listDistance.get(a.getId()),
                                                  listDistance.get(b.getId())));
```

See running code at [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/HTPkHT).